# I keep getting this error when trying to open my website: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'amaqhawe'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm failing to figure out what I did wrong. I've recently added a register/login system on my website and I did everything, including setting up the server info in PHPMYADMIN. Now the problem is that I get an error(SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'amaqhawe'@'localhost' (using password: NO)) when I type in my website address on a browser.

My config.php file

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('South Africa');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','amaqhawe');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','amaqhawe');

//application address
define('DIR','http://amaqhawe.co.za/');
define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@amaqhawe.co.za');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

[image: This is the error.]

Comment: I forgot to mention that this system was working fine on my local server - the problem started now that I'm trying to put it online on the hosting company I'm in.

Answer (score 2):

Check, that user defined at your scripts created and have permissions to using database ( on copying database you transfer data, not users and permissions)

PhpMyAdmin allow do this

Or simple create new user ( look username and password at your configuration script )

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql user credentials. They seem to be incorrect. I guess you need to specify your database password

Answer (score 0):

Check you phpmyadmin config files **config.inc.php**
and change this line

Location :
If you are using Ubuntu/Debian

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

If Redhat/CentOs

```
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

As your password is empty : By default phpmyadmin won't allow empty passwords that is why you are getting: **'amaqhawe'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

So modify the config file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;   // Change this form false to true
```

This will allow empty passwords now.

This may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to connect to database with the default user. (user: root with no password). If you can, probably the problem is with your user.
2. Check your user surely has no password set.
3. Check whether that user has access to the database you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

The website is up and running now. I created a new user and added it to database (`amaqhawe_amaqhawe`). After that my database credentials looked like this:

```
//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','amaqhawe_admin');
define('DBPASS','960721');
define('DBNAME','amaqhawe_amaqhawe');
```

The problem is that I did not write `amaqhawe_user` on my user credentials, I only wrote `user` without including the `amaqhawe_` in the beginning. Thanks a lot for your inputs. You really helped me out big time.